Saving a meta value as an object using useEntityProp
I have a meta key (geographic coordinates) registered as an object with two properties to a custom post type, lat and lng in PHP as follows:
    register_post_meta(
        'event',
        'coordinates',
        [
            'description'  => __( 'Latitude and Longitude', 'zzz' ),
            'show_in_rest' => [
                'schema' => [
                    'type'       => 'object',
                    'properties' => [
                        'lat' => [
                            'type'     => 'number',
                            'optional' => true,
                        ],
                        'lng' => [
                            'type'     => 'number',
                            'optional' => true,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'single'       => true,
            'type'         => 'object',
        ]
    );

I also have a Gutenberg Block that saves the metadata of user-input coordinates, as shown here:
...
    const [ meta, setMeta ] = useEntityProp(
        'postType',
        'event',
        'meta',
        postId
    );
...

onChange={ ( value ) =>
    setMeta( {
        ...meta,
        coordinates: {
            lat: value,
            lng: coordinates?.lng,
        },
    } )
}

When saving the post, I see the POST request to the API sending the data as an object.

The Problem
And yet, the post meta is stored in the database as a serialized array instead of an object.
a:2:{s:3:"lat";d:40.1586012;s:3:"lng";d:-83.0750746;}

Conversely, this (via PHP) saves the meta value as expected (a serialzied object)
$coordinates_obj      = new \stdClass();
$coordinates_obj->lat = 42;
$coordinates_obj->lng = -83.5;

update_post_meta(
    $post_id,
    'coordinates',
    $coordinates_obj
);

I can, of course, cast the array as an object when retrieving the meta value, but is there any apparent reason why it’s not saving as a serialized object in the first place and any way to override the way the value is saved when saving/updating meta values via the block editor?


And yet, the post meta is stored in the database as a serialized array!

This is because all meta values are strings, that's what the database table schema says.
So if you try to pass structured data into it, WordPress tries to be helpful and uses serialize to turn it into a string, then deserialises it when it's retrieved back. Note that this also has security consequences!. This happens for options, transients, user meta, post meta, term meta, etc etc. Anywhere that accepts arbitrary PHP data structures will serialise them down into a string so that it can still be stored. This also goes for JS data structures etc that are sent to the REST API, as well as any structured data you try to pass in via block APIs, it can't be stored as a JS array or a PHP object, it has to be serialised into a string before it can be stored.
There are major performance and practical consequences to this too, querying for values is much harder and sometimes not possible as you can't reliably query sub-parts of a meta value, and MySQL is unaware of any internal structure to the value. It also means if you wanted to do comparisons against your lat/long values that would not be possible.

and any way to override the way the value is saved?

You could declare it as a string and do the serialisation yourself, JSON would be a superior method, and you'd be explicit about how the data is stored.
But fundamentally it will always be a string. For this though, it could be argued that using an object in the first place is a mistake!
For example if you instead store your latitude and longitude in separate values, you can simplify your code, avoid serialising, and you gain the ability to use comparison operators in meta_query.
Generally it's best to avoid storing structured data in post meta unless you intend to serialize it yourself and retrieve it in its entirety, e.g. a JSON or XML fragment, or content.

Thanks for the response! Yes, I know it's always a string, and I fully appreciate the security implications/querying implications.  But it seems like it's perfectly acceptable to store structure data in post meta/options: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/10/03/wp-5-3-supports-object-and-array-meta-types-in-the-rest-api/.  My question at its root is, why is an object serialized as an array in the block editor but correctly serialized as an object via the PHP update_meta function, etc. As I have properly registered the meta, only the properties I explicitly declare can be saved.

@PhilBirnie JavaScript objects are PHP arrays. That's how they're stored. If you use any of that example code exactly as-is it will be stored in the database exactly the same way as yours. When the value is encoded as JSON for the API response it will be returned as an object because that's how associative arrays in PHP are represented.
